# How to show updates to my website deployed on digital ocean?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, digital-ocean

I followed this tutorial to deploy a Flask website on my digital ocean server:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

This is great. But when I update my website, the changes do not appear on the site that is served to visitors. I assume I need to restart something, like nginx or something. But I am pretty unsure exactly what to do. What command should I enter on my droplet's terminal to update and show the new changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart `uwsgi` using

```
sudo systemctl restart myproject
```